# How does openssl command handle PKCS#7 padding added with python

Tags: python, shell, encryption, openssl

I encrypt a (tar) file use python and padding using PKCS#7. This encrypted file is then to a client (a router with OpenWRT). This router uses the (linux) shell with the `openssl` command to decrypt it. This last step however fails with the following info:

```
bad decrypt

2011837512:error:06065064:lib(6):func(101):reason(100):NA:0:

tar: short read
```

Perhaps the problem lies in the padding, so I want to know what arguments to use for `openssl` to avoid this issue. Are there any other commands than `-nopad` related to padding?

The following Python code is used to encrypt the tar file:

```
# Encrypt file
def aes_encrypt_file(in_filename, out_filename, key, iv):
block_size = AES.block_size
pad = lambda s: s + (block_size - len(s) % block_size) \
                    * chr(block_size - len(s) % block_size)
cipher = aes_build_cipher(key, iv)
with open(in_filename, 'rb') as infile:
    with open(out_filename, 'wb') as outfile:
        while True:
            buf = infile.read(1024)
            if len(buf) == 0:
                break
            elif len(buf) % block_size != 0:
                buf = pad(buf)
            outfile.write(cipher.encrypt(buf))
```

The following shell command is used to decrypt the tar file on the router:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -nosalt -K $sum256 -iv $iv -in ${PACKAGE} | tar xzf -
```

Comment: Please re-read the question, are you first decrypting, then encrypting? Post your python code and any openssl information that you have! Currently this question is too broad.

Comment: Thank you for your commend. What I want to know is how does openssl know what I paded in the decrpted file? am I right for the method of padding in the python code?

Comment: And forgive my english..

Comment: No problem, understood it in the end :)

Comment: It looks like something is swallowing some of your error message. `openssl errstr 0x06065064` returns `error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt`. The function `EVP_DecryptFinal_ex` is located in `<openssl src>/crypto/evp/evp_enc.c`. It looks like the error is being generated on line 540 from 1.0.1h sources (search for `EVP_R_BAD_DECRYPT`).

Comment: @jww Thanks. Yes,I have find this from google before,but it did no help.

Comment: Padding bytes are `[1-16]` inclusive (not `[0-15]`). Calculate padding with `pad = block_size - (byte_count(s) % block_size)); if (pad == 0) pad = 16;` I don't read Python well all the time, so I can't tell if that's what you are doing.

Comment: @jww You are right, I have changed the python code to padding bytes [1-16],and  test it now.thank you very much

Comment: This question has some association with mine:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591089/openssl-pkcs5-pkcs7-padding?rq=1][1]

Answer (score 1):

Generally you are moving in the right direction with regards to the AES mode and padding. You however pad and encrypt not the entire plaintext but each and every block of (max) 1024 bytes. This won't decrypt correctly if seen as a single encrypted file, therefore the padding at the end of the plaintext will be incorrect and you will see a failure.

Comment: Thank you very much for every thing you have done.My tar file is about 200KB,and it always changes in a small range.Actually,I find the padding method is not PKCS#7,because if the file size is the multiple of block_size(here is 16),it will never pad.So,I changed the code,and testint in progress.

Comment: An important thing I forgot to say,the tar file will send to client per hour,and the error happens every 10 times.

Comment: Please edit in this information. Reading the padding part is a bit tricky if you don't know lambda. Still, the pad should not be performed on each block; if not all 1024 bytes are read, then this program will error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved, and the following Python code is correct.

```
# Encrypt file
def aes_encrypt_file(in_filename, out_filename, key, iv):
block_size = AES.block_size
pad = lambda s: s + (block_size - len(s) % block_size) \
                    * chr(block_size - len(s) % block_size)
cipher = aes_build_cipher(key, iv)
with open(in_filename, 'rb') as infile:
    with open(out_filename, 'wb') as outfile:
        buf = infile.read()     
        buf = pad(buf)
        outfile.write(cipher.encrypt(buf))
```

@owlstead @jww Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Upvoted your Q/A. Note that just blocks of code are not considered answers. You should clearly indicate what you did to solve the problem in the answer.